# Can I downgrade X in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, xorg, downgrade, accessibility

Is it possible to successfully downgrade X to 1.10.99.* or earlier in 12.04?

I have tried with Synaptic->Package->Force Version, but it only shows me two versions of 1.11.4.  Downgrading would restore some broken accessibility functionality that I rely on to use Ubuntu effectively.

EDIT:

Specifically, the LatchLock feature of Sticky Keys in XKB no longer works.  Two bug reports:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/998877

https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=51955

Comment: You might want to expand your question by editing it to include information about the specific functionality you need. There might be another way to get things working, besides downgrading, that someone could suggest. If there is a bug report (or reports) about the broken functionality, you could include links there too.

Comment: If the latest version has a regression, a bug report needs to be filed.